# Conditional Probability in Selecting Balls from Urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Suppose that balls are randomly removed, one by one, from an urn initially containing one red ball, one blue ball, one yellow ball, and one green ball. What is the probability that the green ball will be removed before the red ball is removed, given that the green ball is removed before the blue ball is removed?

**Attempted Solution:**

I don't know how else to approach this besides brute force. I will bold the ones which satisfy the given, that green was removed before blue.

rbyg, bgyr, **gbyr**, ybgr

rbgy, bgry, **gbry**, ybrg

**rgyb**, bryg, **gybr**, yrbg

**rgby**, brgy, **gyrb**, **yrgb**

rybg, bygr, **gryb**, **ygbr**

**rygb**, byrg, **grby**, **ygrb**

After writing these, I probably could have just calculated that green would be selected before blue with $p$ = $.5$, by symmetry, and that there are $4!$ permutations, giving $12$ arrangements satisfying the given.

Out of these, green is removed before red 8 times giving p = $\frac{8}{12}$ = $.667$

I am looking to see if this is correct and if there is a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method I:  Let $X$ be the event "the green ball is removed before the red" and let $Y$ be the event "the green ball is removed before the blue."  then, of course, $$P(X\,|\,Y)=\frac {P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$$

As you remark, $P(Y)=\frac 12$

$X\cap Y$ is the event "green is removed before both red and blue."  The only ways that can happen are if green is removed first (prob. = $\frac 14$) or if yellow is removed first, and then green (prob. = $\frac 14\times \frac 13 = \frac 1{12}$  Thus  $$P(X \cap Y) = \frac 14 +\frac 1{12}=\frac 4{12}=\frac 13$$

It follows that $$P(X\,|\,Y) = \frac {1/3}{1/2}=\frac 23$$

just as you computed.

Method II. (a method which generalizes to $n$ colors).  Suppose there were many distinct colors.  None of them would matter at all, we only care about the order of $R,B,G$.  Now a priori there are $6$ ways to order these.  Given that $G$ must precede $B$, there are only $3$.  They are $GBR, GRB, RGB$.  Of theese, two have the property that $G$ also precedes $R$ so the answer is $\frac 23$ regardless of the number of other colors.